# MobileFirst 7.1 Direct update triggered in iOS app native when same build & version rebuilt with new provisioning profile

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Is it normal for the iOS app to get direct update when rebuilt with new provisioning profile but the same build and version and no modifications?

We have rebuilt and signed our iOS native code in our MobileFirst platform 7.1 project using the new provisioning profile because the old one has expired profile. We did not modify the code or anything, we just need to build with the new provisioning profile since the iOS app with the old profile cannot be installed.

We didn't expect that direct update to be triggered since it is just the same as the version and build with the old one with expired profile. Seems like it executes the full update from the server. Is it really a normal function or there's a problem with our codes or something? 
We just don't like to get the direct update since it is just the same source code without an additional functionality and just renewed provisioning profile
so that user can download it and install in our enterprise website.
Help please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the new provisioning profile, you're creating a new/different iOS binary.  Therefore, if you're distributing your app through App Center, App Center will interpret this new build as a change that should be propagated to devices running what it now sees as an "old" version of the app.

I don't think there is anything wrong in your code.  The provisioning profile is core to any iOS app.  If you change that, they're going to have to download the new version.